# filtro personalizado em datatable

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, lado-do-servidor

Bom dia!

Tem um certo tempo, que eu venho precisando fazer um filtro avançado no server side.
Eu pensei duas possibilidades, em enviar os parametros no fnserverdata, que não funcionou muito bem, então eu resolvi enviar o parâmetro via Ajax

Segue um exemplo do meu ajax

```
$("#btnFiltrar").click(function(){
    if(document.getElementById("inputNao").checked){
        var inputNao = $("input[id=inputNao]").val();
        $.ajax({
            type:'GET',
            url:'json/ssp.class-license.php',
            data:{
                specialClientesYes:inputNao
            }
        })
    }
});
$("#btnFiltrar").click(function(){
    if($("#cmbVersao").find(":selected").text() != "Selecione"){
        var versao = $("#cmbVersao").find(":selected").text();
        $.ajax({
            type:'GET',
            url:'json/dados-license.php?version='+versao
        })
    }
});
$("#btnFiltrar").click(function(){
    if($("#txtUsuariosDe").val() != ""){
        var usuariosDe = $("#txtUsuariosDe").val();
        $.ajax({
            type:'GET',
            url:'json/ssp.class-license.php',
            data:{
                earlyUsers:usuariosDe
            }
        })
    }
});
```

Minha maior dificuldade é pegar esse valor onde faz o server side e faze-lo filtrar
Como tratar esse valor?

Answer (score 0):

Olhando os exemplos no site do datatables, eu imagino que seja melhor você utilizar a api dele, ao invés de você personalizar o ajax para cada consulta.
Veja os exemplos abaixo:

```
function filterGlobal () {
    $('#example').DataTable().search(
        $('#global_filter').val(),
        $('#global_regex').prop('checked'),
        $('#global_smart').prop('checked')
    ).draw();
}



function filterColumn ( i ) {
    $('#example').DataTable().column( i ).search(
        $('#col'+i+'_filter').val(),
        $('#col'+i+'_regex').prop('checked'),
        $('#col'+i+'_smart').prop('checked')
    ).draw();
}
```